# Management Service does not appera on ISS Console

Tags: .net, iis, deployment

I'm having a hard time to deploy a website. I'm reading tutorials all over the internet and following the instructions. I've downloaded the Web Platform Installer and installed all the asked tools. Specially ISS: Management Service

But when I open IIS Console I can't find the icon Management Service at Management tab.

What should I do?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: My operating system its windows 10

Comment: That service is solely available on Windows Server. Windows 10 is not qualified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 is client OS and Management service only support on server OS. so you could try to use this feature on the server OS.

Thank you for understanding.

Comment: @brunomanguinho If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.